# How to find duplicates in a large project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, refactoring, code-duplication

I am trying to use the "Analyze solution for code clones" to remove code smells and duplication. My project is almost large and every time that I use this option It works for a bit but then it seems the process freezes and does not do anything until I have to clone the window.
Does anyone know what should I do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to use a professional clone-detection tool like [Teamscale](http://teamscale.eu) or [ConQAT](http://www.conqat.org).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So what is the "Analyze solution for code clones" for?

Comment: It is a light-weight prototypical implementation of a naive clone-detection algorithm. So, in principle it does the same thing, but by far not with the robustness and speed that dedicated quality-analysis tools provide.

Answer (score -1):

There are alternative tools, such as our [C# CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/), which has been run across millions of lines of code in many languages over the last 20 years.

CloneDR is based on finding clones using compiler-style parse trees rather than strings of tokens typical of many other detectors (and I think, how the MS detector operates).  As a consequence it produces clones that are aligned with the language structure.    CloneDR can also find clones which are near-misses, and show how the clone instances have been parameterized differently.

[You can see a generated clone report.](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/CSharpExample/index.html)